# Microsoft Windows pop under windows - can anything be done to fix these?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I had not used Windows for a while and recently needed to go back to my old laptop and then I remembered my number #1 annoyance - windows that pop under instead of on top of other windows. An example is using Windows Explorer to delete a large number of items (running for 10 minutes, for example), which pop a window to request administrator permission to delete one item. That window often goes to the very bottom of the stack of windows and eventually I notice it flashing on the task bar. Is there any way to fix this behavior to get those windows to always appear on top? Any dialog that wants to get my attention should be at the top! This has been a long-term behavior of Windows since before Windows-7.

Comment: Are you talking about the UAC prompt?  If not you really need to edit your question and clarify it.

Comment: If you are using Windows 10, Pop On Top outnumber Pop Under by 7 or 8 to 1.  But all are on the Taskbar

Comment: No, because EVERYONE else apart from you go apoplectic at having the focus stolen. It has been this way since Windows 98 (so 22 years) / Windows 2000. You can read the rules here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow.

Comment: It's by design. Imagine if you are working on a document and typing something halfway and windows keep popping to the top. That would be very disruptive

Comment: I find it rather irritating if I have a long-running process, which has stopped with a dialog that I cannot see while I am working elsewhere. I'm expecting that process to keep on working, but instead, lots of time gets wasted. Pop-up dialogs should pop-up. And, no, this isn't UAC prompt, but the example I gave was a prompt "you need administrator permissions to delete this file prompt".